# How to use Azure using directive from VSCode on Ubuntu w/ C#

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, vscode-extensions

when trying to add the following using directive in Program.cs:

```
using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Producer;
```

it says

```
The type or namespace name 'Azure' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have added most of the Azure extentions and run a `dotnet restore` on the project, but still not working. How do i add this using-directive/assembly-reference on linux?

[image]

This is running on a ubuntu machine (20.04) with VS code and dotnettt core SKD 5.0

Comment: did you try installing nuget package at all in the project and see if it works ?
link to package : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/5.6.0?preview=1

Comment: Can you shared your project file?   My guess is that you may not be referencing the package.

Comment: @manivi Thanks, that did it for me ``` dotnet add package Azure.Messaging.EventHubs```